# Не могу запустить бота в VK (BotLongPoll API)

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Никак не могу запустить бота, постоянно вот такая ошибка:  [image]

**run.py**

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from bot import GameManager


    def write_msg(user_id, message):
        vk.method('messages.send', {'user_id': user_id, 'message': message})


    file = open("token.txt", "r")
    token = file.readline()

    vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, 182936061)

    print("Server started")
    for event in longpoll.listen():
        if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
            if event.to_me:
                print('New message:')
                print(f'For me by: {event.user_id}', end='')

                bot = GameManager(event.user_id)
                write_msg(event.user_id, bot.new_message(event.text))

                print('Text: ', event.text)
```

**Класс моего бота**

```
import vk_api
import bs4 as bs4
import requests
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


class GameManager:

    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self._USER_ID = user_id
        self._USERNAME = self._get_user_name_from_vk_id(user_id)
        self._COMMANDS = ["Привет", "Помощь"]

    def _get_user_name_from_vk_id(self, user_id):
        request = requests.get("https://vk.com/id" + str(user_id))
        bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")

        user_name = self._clean_all_tag_from_str(bs.findAll("title")[0])

        return user_name.split()[0]

    @staticmethod
    def _clean_all_tag_from_str(string_line):
        """
        Очистка строки stringLine от тэгов и их содержимых
        :param string_line: Очищаемая строка
        :return: очищенная строка
        """
        result = ""
        not_skip = True
        for i in list(string_line):
            if not_skip:
                if i == "<":
                    not_skip = False
                else:
                    result += i
            else:
                if i == ">":
                    not_skip = True

        return result

    def new_message(self, message):
        if message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[0]:
            return f"День добрый, {self._USERNAME}!"
        elif message.upper() == self._COMMANDS[1]:
            return f"До свидания, {self._USERNAME}."
        else:
            return "Извините, я Вас не понял("
```

Comment: У Вас включен `longPoll` в настройках сообщества?

Comment: Да, включен longpoll версии 5.95

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была решена созданием нового ключа в настройках сообщества.